# Starting MainActivity after Firebase Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have already researched about how to start a new activity after a Login, but my app keeps crashing whenever I try to implement a new activity.

I got my launcher class Login Activity prompting for authentication via username-pw/Facebook/Google.

Right now I am trying to start the new activity in the onActivityResult method, but keeps crashing. Tried different ways to start it, but right now Im lost.

I managed to start a new fragment after clicking button, or start a new activity, but the login is giving me troubles.

Thanks for your help - much appreciated!

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //everything for firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //user already signed in
            Log.d("AUTH", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        } else {
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(
                                    Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()))
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
        findViewById(R.id.log_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //user logged in
                Log.d("AUTH", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

                Uri contentUri = data.getData();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                        .setData(contentUri));

               // Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                // LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                /* TEST: START RANDOM FRAGMENT FROM THE ACTIVITY
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = LoginActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                TrainingFragment trainingFragment = new TrainingFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, trainingFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();*/

            }
            else {
                //user not authenticated
                Log.d("AUTH", "NOT AUTHENTICATED");
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.log_out_button) {
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Log.d("AUTH", "USER LOGGED OUT!");
                            //Fragment newFragment = new HomeFragment(); try to start new activity?
                            //switch to another fragment saying bye or some back next time or sth and then add a button with a "close app" function
                           /* android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = LoginActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            TrainingFragment trainingFragment = new TrainingFragment();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, trainingFragment);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit(); */
                           finish(); //finish ends not only the activity, but the application, without it, the switch from activity to fragment functions :)


                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR LOG

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentiction, PID: 28367
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentiction/com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2822)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2897)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                      at com.example.vreeni.firebaseauthentication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2775)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2897) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Error log please..

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error log added

Answer (score 0):

Alright, apparently it got mixed up, as I initially had 2 seperate projects I merged together.
The themes in the style file for the first activity and the following ones contained different information regarding the actionBar.
Also, I had not initialized the second activity in the Manifest.
Just had been staring at the code for too long to not notice this.
Question solved :)